# set Latest Event Info

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am using android studio,i am working on a part of code, this a part of code that is from an eclipse project that i covert it to android studio.
the problem is in this :

```
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, text,
        getText(R.string.notification_subtitle), contentIntent);
```

`setLatestEventInfo` is red and it can not launch the app, how can if fix this?

```
/**
 * Show a notification while this service is running.
 */
private void showNotification() {
    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.app_name);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_notification, null,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    Intent pedometerIntent = new Intent();
    pedometerIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, Pedometer.class));
    pedometerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            pedometerIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, text,
            getText(R.string.notification_subtitle), contentIntent);

    mNM.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);
}
```

This is the error :

```
Error:(375, 21) error: cannot find symbol method setLatestEventInfo(StepService,CharSequence,CharSequence,PendingIntent)
```

and this :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that Google has removed this method since API 23. For more information read here: [Notification](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html).

While importing your project from Eclipse to Android Studio, the target must have changed from something below 23 to 23 or above. Hence this method won't be accessible anymore.

Try changing your notification code to:

```
Intent pedometerIntent = new Intent();
pedometerIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, Pedometer.class));
pedometerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        pedometerIntent, 0);

CharSequence text = getText(R.string.app_name);
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setShowWhen(true)
        .setContentTitle(text)
        .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_subtitle))
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .build();

notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

mNM.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);
```

Comment: thanks you for you answer , i dont know why but i get a new error `.setTicker(System.currentTimeMillis())`Error:(375, 52) error: incompatible types: long cannot be converted to CharSequence and on the ticker error is in builder can not be apply

Comment: new error is `.setTicker(System.currentTimeMillis())`Error:(375, 52) error: incompatible types: long cannot be converted to CharSequence and on the ticker error is in builder can not be apply